# Deleting the array with splice not working properly in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

**Splice not working with Angularjs**
My splice code is not working. I am trying to delete it from Ui on basis of index from array list.

```
$scope.deleteDoc = function (index) {
    var Doc = ($filter('orderBy')(($filter('filter')($filter('filter')($scope.Doclist, $scope.parametr), $scope.any)), $scope.myOrderBy)[index]);
    //debugger;
    var IsConf = confirm('آیا از حذف ' + Doc.Title + ' اطمینان دارید؟ ');
    if (IsConf) {
        $http.post('/Home/Delete/' + Doc.Id)
            .then(function onsuccess(response) {
                alert(Doc.Title + '!! رکورد حذف شد ');
                debugger
                $scope.Doclist.splice(index, 1);
            }, function onfaild(response) {
                alert('خطا هنگام حذف اطلاعات!!');
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I think it could be more easy to figure if you break down the long filter expression to several seperated expressions with temp vars. So it will be more debuggable. 2. Instead of using angular filters this way, you can use es6 array filter/sort... native functions or lodash equivalents. 3. What is the error that is given, or what point in the code you don't get the expected result and what result do you get.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem